# JavaScript and the Enterprise

Tags: javascript, security, enterprise

I figure this is a good place to ask this question:

Is anyone aware of the "standard" procedure or know how common it is these days that enterprise businesses disable JavaScript (or only allow it on a specified list of websites)?

Any information someone can link me to back up anything would be awesome...I haven't been able to find much on the topic.

Comment: I Googled "business disabling javascript" and found: http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?biz.5.410878.8

Comment: @MathSquared11235 That article is from late '06.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that many people disable JavaScript for security reasons. JavaScript should never be a critical aspect of your site.

Comment: @MathSquared11235: tell that to meebo or google docs...

Comment: Yeah Google docs still has a way to go to really be accepted into the enterprise. Still though any network admin could just allow Google docs and be done with it. What I am wondering is recent data (estimates will wor) on how many Fortune 1000 disable js for unidentified sites.

Comment: @user1114330: it seems that the enterprise-architect tag is not suitable for this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yahoo keeps track of this for everyone to benefit from:

http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/many-users-javascript-disabled-14121.html.

I would stick to bigger companies like Yahoo, Google, etc. when mining this type of data.

Comment: It's about 2%, by now it's probably about 1.X%.  Do you need more resolution?  Hard numbers are hard to come by in web.  That's a pretty good estimate.

Comment: Yeah overall numbers are helpful...1.X% to 2% sounds about right. What  I am curious about is how much higher does this number get when we are only talking about Fortune 1000?

Comment: Do you mean on private corporate intranets or the public internet?